# How to get form postdata that uses field names with square brackets as structured objects in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have such a form:

```html
<form action="{% url 'requerimento' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="requerente[nome]">
    <input type="text" name="requerente[endereco]">
    <input type="text" name="representante[nome]">
    <input type="text" name="representante[endereco]">
    <input type="file" name="anexo[0]">
    <input type="file" name="anexo[1]">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

It is evaluated by this view:

```py
def teste(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST:
            pp(request.POST.dict())
        if request.FILES:
            pp(request.FILES.dict())
    return render(request, 'interface/teste.html')
```

It outputs this to console:

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'iEokZx8pJz73BtT8nNiIPH9oBkepgFLN5AfgBTgGstg4WixbBG3gF1XeELVvEUW3',
 'requerente[nome]': 'a',
 'requerente[endereco]': 'b',
 'representante[nome]': 'c',
 'representante[endereco]': 'd'}
{'anexo[0]': <InMemoryUploadedFile: file1.pdf (application/pdf)>,
 'anexo[1]': <InMemoryUploadedFile: file2.pdf (application/pdf)>}
```

***Is it possible, instead, to retrieve or easily convert these data in a structured fashion so like below?***

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'iEokZx8pJz73BtT8nNiIPH9oBkepgFLN5AfgBTgGstg4WixbBG3gF1XeELVvEUW3',
 'requerente': {'nome': 'a', 'endereco': 'b'},
 'representante': {'nome': 'a', 'endereco': 'd'} }
{'anexo': [
    <InMemoryUploadedFile: file1.pdf (application/pdf)>,
    <InMemoryUploadedFile: file2.pdf (application/pdf)> ]}
```